# sitecore web form for marketers form post to external url

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

We are using Sitecore's Web form for Marketer's module to generate forms. Now i have a special requirement, i need to created a form using Web Form for Marketer's module which will post to an extrenal site web page. External site web page is expecting certain form fields so i need to make sure that form fields generated by Web Form for Marketer has id/name as we want to send it to page on external site.

Is this possible using web form for marketers? If not what would be best practice to have such form in sitecore?

We are using sitecore 6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement it is to create custom Web Forms for Marketers *Save Action*, and assign it to the form.

In that action, just read the field values and post data to external form using **WebRequest**, see the example here - [How to submit http form using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273998/how-to-submit-http-form-using-c-sharp)