# WFFM form POST and redirect

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I've roughly followed this example but it doesnt solve my Sitecore-related redirect problem.
[sitecore web form for marketers form post to external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593799/sitecore-web-form-for-marketers-form-post-to-external-url)

I've confirmed that my form POST works properly by using a 3rd party POST test tool. The problem I'm having is that in Sitecore they use a successMode to determine what the user wants todo if the submit is a success. If the user selects successmode/message, the form redirects back to a thank you message. If the user selects successmode/redirect, the success method pipeline looks for the success page value in the form and then a redirect happens to that URL. The problem with the redirect is that it loses my POST data.

Can anyone provide a Sitecore example of how they executed a form POST, and then redirect to the target external URL without losing POST values?

Did you use the successmode settings in the form?

I'm debating whether to overrride the successmode redirect pipeline, add conditions and test but I'm open to a solution that could include jquery.

Here's is my code:

```
        using Sitecore.Data;
    using Sitecore.Form.Core.Client.Data.Submit;
    using Sitecore.Form.Core.Controls.Data;
    using Sitecore.Form.Submit;
    using System.Web;
    using Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using Sitecore.Text;
    using Sitecore.Forms.Core.Data;
    using Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration;
    using Sitecore.Forms.Core.Crm;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text;

    namespace XXXWffmExternals
    {
        public class Redirect : ISaveAction      
        {                
            UrlString url = new UrlString("https://XXX.XXX/default.asp");

            public virtual void Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
            {
                String strResult = "";            
                strResult = setPost(url.ToString(), fields); 

            }

            public String setPost(string url, AdaptedResultList fieldListForPOST)
            {
                String resultReturn = "";

                AdaptedControlResult firstname = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.First_Name, "First_Name");
                AdaptedControlResult lastname = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Last_Name, "Last_Name");
                AdaptedControlResult billingaddress = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Billing_Address, "Billing_Address");
                AdaptedControlResult billingcity = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Billing_City, "Billing_City");
                AdaptedControlResult billingstate = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Billing_State, "Billing_State");
                AdaptedControlResult billingzip = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Billing_Zip, "Billing_Zip");
                AdaptedControlResult billingphone = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Billing_Phone, "Billing_Phone");
                AdaptedControlResult email = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Email, "Email");
                AdaptedControlResult amount = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Amount, "Amount");
                AdaptedControlResult desc = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Description, "Description");
                AdaptedControlResult login = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Login, "Login");
                AdaptedControlResult acct = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Account, "Account");
                AdaptedControlResult fund = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Fund, "Fund");
                AdaptedControlResult org = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Org, "Org");

                AdaptedControlResult source_code = fieldListForPOST.GetEntry(this.Source_Code, "Source_Code");

                String post =
                    "First_Name=" + firstname.Value +
                    "&Last_Name=" + lastname.Value +
                    "&Billing_Address=" + billingaddress.Value +
                    "&Billing_City=" + billingcity.Value +
                    "&Billing_State=" + billingstate.Value +
                    "&Billing_Zip=" + billingzip.Value +
                    "&Billing_Phone=" + billingphone.Value +
                    "&Email=" + email.Value +
                    "&Amount=" + amount.Value +
                    "&Description=" + desc.Value +
                    "&Login=" + login.Value +
                    "&Account=" + acct.Value +
                    "&Fund=" + fund.Value +
                    "&Org=" + org.Value +
                    "&Invoice_Num=" + "DVXXXX";

                resultReturn = sendPost(url.ToString(), post); 

                return resultReturn;

            }

            public String sendPost(string url, string post)
            {

                String result = "";

                HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                objRequest.Method = "POST";
                // Set credentials to use for this request.
                objRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                // Convert POST data to a byte array.           
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post);

                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                objRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = objRequest.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();
                // Get the response.
                WebResponse response = objRequest.GetResponse();                      
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                result = reader.ReadToEnd ();

                // Clean up the streams.
                reader.Close ();
                dataStream.Close ();
                response.Close ();
                return result;      


            }



            public string First_Name { get; set; }       
            public string Last_Name { get; set; }       
            public string Billing_Address { get; set; }
            public string Billing_City { get; set; }
            public string Billing_State { get; set; }
            public string Billing_Zip { get; set; }
            public string Billing_Phone { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Amount { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Login { get; set; }
            public string Account { get; set; }
            public string Fund { get; set; }
            public string Org { get; set; }
            public string Invoice_Num { get; set; }
            public string Source_Code { get; set; }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use WFFM for the form if you don't want to invoke any of the WFFM functionality?  The point of WFFM is to allow marking people to create their own forms without any Developer input.  You're having to edit all the post data in your code which pretty much eliminates the ability for anyone to edit the form without developer input. I'd say, if you're going to go through the process of writing all the code to submit your code by hand, you can use a Sitecore item to create the form and then use your own code for processing.  Skip WFFM.  It's a lot more work to do things as you suggested than to just manually create a form.

If you really need any WFFM end functionality, you can easily call them... it's still way easier than trying to override WFFM base functionality to inject your own functionality.

Comment: Command template has been created and deployed to duplicate my base form. So when user clicks payment form, they have a base payment form created at their web form site root w/new ids. The question was specifically about POSTing to external URL. Btw, overriding is a common practice when a developer must provide solutions for the marketer and in our case its required for a solution like this. Please tell me how you create input type fields within form tags without using WFFM.

Comment: If I came across as rude, I apologize.  I didn't mean to.  It just seemed to me, based on what you asked, that you were basically writing all your own code to handle a form submittal and not using any of the WFFM functionality.

Comment: To answer your question though, simply put, using WFFM is easy, but it's fairly limited  in that customization forces you to work within the bounds of the module. If you're dead set on using the WFFM module, what I'd suggest you do here is create your own custom save action and then assign it to the form. If you look at the Reference materials for the WFFM documentation, there's a section about creating a save action. You can write all your own code to handle submitting to an external site and it gives you access to the fields as an object.

Comment: This has been executed from a custom successmode command & a save action from the form, hence the "ISaveAction" interface. Sitecore contains built in js postback methods that cannot be changed. So once the postback occurs, the POST data is wiped. The problem is not submitting to another site (been there), its persisting the values through the postback.

Comment: Wow. Good luck with this. I think that between your condescending attitude towards someone who is only trying to help and your stubborn insistence that your square peg does in fact fit in a round hole, I'm gonna bow out and leave you to this. Good luck.