# Connecting to .aspx site from c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm trying to build c# application, which notify me when there is an "update" in site.
The site login form contains 3 textboxes, and it's login.aspx.

My question is, how can I "send" the 3 details to the site and connect(authenticate) from the application I want to build in c#, and if it's possible, how can I do it?
I looked for any guide or something to read about this but haven't found.

Comment: you need to simulate web-browser's behavior, such as: authentication, cookie, and redirection. so the WebClient class may help you

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `WebClient` class. More info on this class can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx

And a nice example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4

Comment: Thanks, But there is a problem. I understand that I need to know the parameters that the page sends, but when I tried with sniffer I see that the content is encrypted to a lot of letters. How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

[First you need post a form using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273998/680372)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (args[0]);

            // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
            request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
            request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
            // Set credentials to use for this request.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

            Console.WriteLine ("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
            Console.WriteLine ("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

            // Get the stream associated with the response.
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

            // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
            Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
            response.Close ();
            readStream.Close ();
```

[then try to save cookie, its required to store aspnet_session_id into client for future requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740752/how-to-login-with-webclient-c-sharp)

```
private class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }
    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer c)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = c;
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

ensure you send the and restore aspnet_session_id on each request.
And bingo!!

I recommend you to read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443).