# Can I do method 'Get' then 'Post' in a HTTPWebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

First, I apologize for the english ability ^^

target: I want POST a **data** to a Login website.
but the **data** contain a **value** (the **value** different after refresh website) that i must GET from website.
So, i do 'GET' method first, and get the **value**, then i do 'POST' method & i get the error 'This property cannot be set after writing has started.' in 'content-length'

My code:

```
         HttpWebRequest wr = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.fshare.vn/login") as HttpWebRequest;
        wr.KeepAlive = true;

        // get the value
        HttpWebResponse wrep = wr.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream streamReponse = wrep.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamReponse);
        string httpDoc = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string fs_csrt = getfs_csrf(httpDoc);

        wr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        wr.CookieContainer.Add(wrep.Cookies);

        reader.Close();
        streamReponse.Close();
        wrep.Close();


        // Post into website

        string postDataString = @"POST /login fs_csrf={0}
                            &LoginForm%5Bemail%5D=abcd%40yahoo.com.vn
                            &LoginForm%5Bpassword%5D=abcd
                            &LoginForm%5Bcheckloginpopup%5D=0
                            &LoginForm%5BrememberMe%5D=0
                            &yt0=%C4%90%C4%83ng+nh%E1%BA%ADp
                            ";
        postDataString = string.Format(postDataString, fs_csrt);
        MessageBox.Show("I will post: " + postDataString);

        byte[] postDatabyte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postDataString);



        wr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36";
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //wr.ContentLength = postDatabyte.Length;

        Stream stream = wr.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(postDatabyte, 0, postDatabyte.Length);
        stream.Close();

        // get the result
        HttpWebResponse wrep2 = wr.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream streamReponse2 = wrep2.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(streamReponse2);
        string httpDoc2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();

        Clipboard.SetText(httpDoc2);
        MessageBox.Show("Post done");
```

Please help me T_T

Comment: Why did you reuse wr?

Comment: because, the value i need get will be change if re-create wr :(

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because request Type **Get** can not have body.

You should create another request object by invoking `Create` method of `HttpWebRequest` and then use that object to post the data.

```
HttpWebRequest anotherWR = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.fshare.vn/login") as HttpWebRequest;
anotherWR.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36";
anotherWR.Method = "POST";
anotherWR.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
anotherWR.KeepAlive = true;
anotherWR.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Stream stream = wr.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(postDatabyte, 0, postDatabyte.Length);
stream.Close();

...
...
...
//and your logic...
```

Comment: no, if re-create the request, the VALUE i need get will change :(

Comment: Nothing is getting stored in request object! which value are you talking about?

Comment: each time i access 'fshare.vn', i get a 'fs_csrt' value:
<input type="hidden" value="697f561bd518fff454dba60b50ddc2b1bb2c85ec" name="fs_csrf">

the fs_csrt use to login website. But fs_csrt will be change when i create  new resquest

Comment: You don't require to download form html first and then do post the form. you can directly do it if you know where to post the form (form url). Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274137/1505865)