# How to pass long value in url c# web applications?

Tags: c#

How to pass long value in url c# web applications

QueryString using passing a base64 value(Converting image to  base64) in two  different applications..

Comment: Why would you pass an image as a querystring?

Comment: is there anyway to Call one asp to another asp web appications....now we tried to image convert to base64 string and give one error message ...Request url too long.

Comment: are you using the mvc ?

Comment: Not using the mvc

Answer (score 0):

For images you should be using POST, which streams lots of data to the server. GET, which passes data in the URL is only for small amounts of data.

[How to submit http form using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273998/how-to-submit-http-form-using-c-sharp)